# Prove $n^n-1 \geq n^\frac{n+1}{2}(n-1)$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^+, n^n-1 \geq n^\frac{n+1}{2}(n-1)$.

Is the following a valid approach or am I overthinking this?

$\begin{align}
&n^n-1 \geq n^\frac{n+1}{2}(n-1)\\
\iff &n^n-n^0 \geq n^{\frac{n+1}{2}+1}-n^\frac{n+1}{2}\\
\iff &\log_n(n^n)-\log_n(n^0) \geq \log_n(n^{\frac{n+1}{2}+1})-\log_n(n^\frac{n+1}{2})\\
\iff &n\log_n(n)-0\log_n(n) \geq \left(\frac{n+1}{2}+1\right)\log_n(n)-\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)\log_n(n)\\
\iff &n \geq \frac{n+1}{2}+1-\frac{n+1}{2}\\
\iff &n \geq 1\\
\end{align}$

Since $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ this is true, so read the proof bottom to top.

My other idea was to show the left side grows faster than the right, and since it is equal at n=1 it is therefore greater for all n.

Comment: That's not how logarithms work. At any rate, I'd say you're overthinking it. $n$ will quickly become larger than $\frac n2+\frac 3{2}$. When?

Answer (score 1):

We can also use that since $n^n-1=(n-1)(n^{n-1}+n^{n-2}+\ldots+n+1)$

$$n^n-1 \geq n^\frac{n+1}{2}(n-1) \iff (n^{n-1}+n^{n-2}+\ldots+n+1)^2\ge n^{n+1}$$

and for $n\ge 3$

$$(n^{n-1}+n^{n-2}+\ldots+n+1)^2 \ge (n^{n-1})^2=n^{2n-2}\ge n^{n+1}$$

then check directly the cases for $n=1,2$.

Answer (score 1):

The following log rules hold, 
$$\mathcal{log(ab) = log(a) + log(b)}$$
$$\mathcal{log(\frac{a}{b}) = log(a) - log(b)}$$
The following does not, 
$$\mathcal{log(a+b) = log(a) + log(b)}$$
The other answers are more elegant and are proofs, this is not a proof but is more intuitive and inline with what you started out with,
$$n^n-1 \geq n^\frac{n+1}{2}(n-1)$$
Taking log on both sides,
$$log(n^{n}-1) > (\frac{n+1}{2})log(n) + log(n-1)$$
For large values of $n$ i.e $n>>1$, $n^n - 1 \approx n^n$ ,Hence, the above equation becomes,
$$nlog(n)>\frac{n+3}{2}log(n)$$
$$n > \frac{n+3}{2}$$
Which holds, for all $$n>3$$

Answer (score 0):

For any $n\geq 3$ we have
$$\frac{n^n-1}{n-1} = \underbrace{n^{n-1}+n^{n-2}+\ldots+n^2}_{n-2\text{ terms}}+n+1\stackrel{\text{AM-GM}}{\geq}(n-2)\cdot n^{\frac{n+1}{2}}+n+1>n^{\frac{n+1}{2}} $$
and it just remains to check the cases $n\in\{1,2\}$ by hand.